# SignalR sends duplicate messages after redeploy to AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, signalr, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I have small SignalR project with one hub. The hub adds all users to one test group. Message handler sends messages to the same group.

Locally the service works as expected. When it's deployed to AWS ECS for some time all returned messages are duplicated. I have CloudWatch logs added to message handler with log that message is being send and log is not duplicated.

Few implementation/configuration details:

1. Sticky sessions are disabled but WebSocket only transport layer is enabled and FE has SkipNegotiation = true
2. I have just one task configured under LB.

Any idea what can be the issue or what needs to be checked to find the issue?

```
//Program.cs

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(sp => RedisConnection.Connect(redisConfig));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRedisClient, RedisClient>();

var signalRBuilder = builder.Services.AddSignalR();

signalRBuilder.AddStackExchangeRedis(c => {
    c.Configuration = RedisConnection.GetConfigurationOptions(redisConfig);
    c.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = "";
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapHub<TestHub>("/testhub", options =>
{
    options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
});

var redisClient = app.Services.GetService<IRedisClient>();

var messageHandlers = new List<IBaseMessageHandler>
{
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<TestMessageHandler>(app.Services)
};

foreach (var messageHandler in messageHandlers)
{
    redisClient?.SubscribeToRedisChannel(messageHandler.GetChannelName(), (IRedisMessageHandler)messageHandler);
}

app.Run();
```

```
//MessageHandler
public class TestMessageHandler : IBaseMessageHandler, IRedisMessageHandler
{
    private readonly IHubContext<TestHub> _hubContext;
    
    public TestMessageHandler(IHubContext<TestHub> hubContext, ILogger<TestMessageHandler> logger)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public string GetChannelName()
    {
        return typeof(TestMessage).Name;
    }

    public void Handle(RedisValue message)
    {
        ContextualMessage<TestMessage> contextualMessage;

        try
        {
            contextualMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContextualMessage<TestMessage>>(message.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            _logger.LogError("Unable to deserialize message: {message}", message.ToString());
            throw;
        }

        _logger.LogDebug("send message to testGroup");

        _hubContext
            .Clients
            .Group("testGroup")
            .SendAsync(GetChannelName(), contextualMessage.Message);
    }
}
```

```
//Hub
public class TestHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ILogger<TestHub> logger;

    public TestHub(ILogger<TestHub> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        logger.LogDebug("TestHub construct");
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        logger.LogDebug("Connected");
        await AddGroups();
        
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        logger.LogDebug("Disconnected");
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }

    private async Task AddGroups()
    {
        var group = "testGroup";

        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, group);
    }
}
```

```
//Send Notification

await _redisClient.SendNotification(message.Message.GetType().Name, message2);
```

I already removed all additional stuff to reduce possible impact.

Comment: EDIT:
updated c.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = "";
to c.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

And it's working now. But I have a feeling it's not good idea to put guid here. From what I understand when we redeploy ECS instance - for some period of time we have 2 running tasks and every task should have unique ChannelPrefix, right? But is there any "more clean" way to have it unique?